# Node.js error after uploaded to cPanel: Namecheap

Tags: node.js, deployment, backend, cpanel, namecheap

I created my Node.js Sequelize REST API with MySQL and after it's finished it works fine without any error.

After I deployed it to Namecheap cPanel, it returns 503 error:

> Error: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found
> (required by
> /home/blacopql/nodevenv/nodejs/14/lib/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-glibc-x64/node_sqlite3.node)
> at Object.Module._extensions..node
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:18) at Module.load
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32) at Function.Module._load
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12) at Module.require
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) at require
> (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18) at Object.
> (/home/blacopql/nodevenv/nodejs/14/lib/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js:4:17)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14) at
> Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32) at
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12) { code:
> 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'

Comment: have you installed build-essential system package?

Comment: no i havent i didnt even build it as i saw on youtube no one did so i didnt can you tell me what to do

Comment: not all but some libs like sqlite3 may require building, see the docs https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3#installing additionally your building against the cpu arch, os type etc, a node_modules built on pc1 won't necessarily work on pc2, you need rebuild

Comment: to build, your need build-essential system package, which in turn brings in the shared object libs and g++ compiler etc